# OpenImaj Asift issue

Tags: java, image-processing, openimaj, asift

I found [this](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/master/demos/examples/src/main/java/org/openimaj/examples/image/feature/local/ASIFTMatchingExample.java) sample code on github.
It supposed to extract local features from 2 photos using ASIFT and then compare those features. On similar photos I get ok-ish output, but on different photos I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhiwN.png)

Does anyone know to to set te comparison parameters in order to get e better output?
ps: code is on the obove link

Comment: Read this: http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/sift-and-feature-matching.html
Everything about consistent matching of SIFT is also applicable to ASIFT

Comment: thank you, I will read it tonight, and come back with results

Comment: Well, it seems that matcher gets better results. It's not matching different images anymore. But in some cases it's not finding enough matcher. I will try some other matchers, too